# POST usando Retrofit não está retornando para a função OnResponse

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Minha aplicação é feita com Kotlin Retrofit e Gson.

Tenho diversos gets para buscar informações e funcionam normalmente, manipulo os dados que retornam no OnResponse e ok, funciona normalmente.
Porém quando executo como um POST isso não acontece, nunca chega no OnResponse.
O Json é enviado corretamente para o servidor, que retorna status 201 de criado, mas mesmo assim o código do OnResponse nunca é executado, portanto não consigo controlar quando realmente deu certo o POST.

O que será que está errado aqui?

Initializer:

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://myserverurl.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
fun orderService    ()  = retrofit.create(OrderService   ::class.java)
```

OrderService.kt

```
interface OrderService {
    @POST("pedido")
    fun insert(@Body order: OrderEntity, @Header("mykey") myKey:String) : Call<OrderEntity>
}
```

Chamada:

```
val call = RetrofitInitializer().orderService().insert(order, mMyKey)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<OrderEntity> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<OrderEntity>?,
                                response: Response<OrderEntity>?) {
            response?.body()?.let {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "It works!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<OrderEntity>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)
        }
    })
```

Lembrando que o request funciona, só não retorna pro onResponse.

Comment: opa, blza!? já colocou um debug no onResponse e no onFailure? pode esta dando erro 500 e caindo na falha. Casa de falha vc consegue pegar o que esta acontecendo.
Já tentou no postman? está tudo certo? por ele é mais facil testar seus endpoints

Comment: Eai, blz e vc? Então, no postman retorna um json dos dados que enviei e status 201 que foi criado com sucesso (realmente foi). Tentei debugar em todas as linhas basicamente dentro do enqueue mas parece nunca "chegar lá"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Na verdade o problema era bem outro.
Debugando melhor percebi que estava retornando para o OnResponse mas com código 500, e então descobri que um dos campos estava dando um problema na API que não apareceu nos meus testes no Postman.
O erro estava acontecendo no response da API que não estava convertendo um valor de data corretamente, acarretando no status 500 mesmo tendo salvo o registro corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Percebi uma coisa na sua interface, na versão 2 do retrofit os dados codificados por formulário são enviados quando `@FormUrlEncoded`. Cada par de valores-chave é anotado com @Fiel do nome e o objeto fornecendo o valor.
Faça no seguinte padrão:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Tokencelular")
Call<TokenModel> gravaToken(@Field("tokenDevice") String tokenDevice);
```

Nos seus métodos GET não é preciso.

Para saber mais, visite a documentação: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ e vá no tópico **FORM ENCODED AND MULTIPART**

Abraços!

Comment: Vou testar e te retorno, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações com base nisso mas não deu mt certo.. Se esse fosse o caso a requisição nem chegaria a ser enviada e recebida pelo servidor, certo? Neste caso envia corretamente mas não consigo pegar o retorno.
Tentei usar o Field no lugar do Body, é isso mesmo? Pelo que entendi esse FormUrlEncoded é necessario para enviar além do nó dos dados do formulario, enviar também um nó com uma chave de autenticação por exemplo dentro do meu JSON? No meu caso coloco a chave no Header. No Logcat não apareceu nada, nem o Failure